# « Publication de bonnes feuilles » : impact de la détermination sur le sens ?

Tags: sens, articles, terminologie, déterminants

Dans un article on lit :

> Le livre, dont le [*nom du journal*] publie lundi **les bonnes feuilles**, est bâti autour d'entretiens avec un ancien conseiller
>   [...]

Le *TLFi* a sous le sens 3 de [*feuille*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/feuille), en imprimerie, la locution :

> ♦ *Bonne feuille*. Feuille de tirage définitif. *Je me vois à mon tour
>   lisant les premières pages des bonnes feuilles d'Aimée* (Du Bos,
>   *Journal*, 1925, p. 349).

[*Larousse*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/feuille/33463/locution?q=bonne%20feuille#329134) a, toujours en imprimerie :

> **Bonne(s) feuille(s)**, premières feuilles d'une impression avant rognage et reliure ; extrait d'un ouvrage publié dans la presse avant
>   sa parution.

[*Ac.9*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/feuille) fait suivre les deux éléments plus distinctement :

> *Bonnes feuilles*, feuilles du tirage définitif d'un ouvrage, avant brochage ou reliure. La critique a reçu ce livre en bonnes feuilles.
>   *Publication de bonnes feuilles*, publication dans la presse d'extraits d'un ouvrage imprimé avant la mise en vente du volume.

En d'autres termes, quand il ne s'agit pas directement du contexte original de l'imprimerie, il s'agit essentiellement d'*extraits choisis* avant publication. *DLHF/Rey* indique (1798) « première impression d'un livre », d'où vient ensuite *texte publié avant la sortie*.

---

- Que doit-on s'attendre à retrouver au journal en question : les premières pages du livre, toutes les pages de la version définitive destinée à la mise sous presse, ou des extraits sélectionnés ? Y a-t-il une différence entre la publication de bonnes feuilles et celle d'**extraits choisis** ou d'une sélection d'extraits, autre que de se situer dans le premier cas à un moment antérieur à celui de la publication ?
- Y a-t-il une nuance entre *publier **des** bonnes feuilles* et *publier **les** bonnes feuilles* ; doit-on utiliser le déterminant indéfini *des* plutôt que le défini *les* pour rendre le sens étayé en deuxième lieu par *Ac.9* (*publication de bonnes feuilles*) ; y a-t-il confusion dans l'extrait présenté en introduction avec la *qualité* de la sélection (les = les seules dignes d'intérêt) ? Au final n'a-t-on pas utilisé un article défini pour qualifier l'indéfini, c'est-à-dire qu'il n'y a pas un nombre déterminé d'extraits a priori (on ne dirait pas qu'ils ont *publié les extraits*, ni même *choisis* ; plutôt publier *des extraits*, *les extraits qu'ils ont choisis*, *leurs extraits* à la limite), c'est un choix du journal, et on n'étaye pas non plus la nature concrète de la sélection qu'il a effectué ([...] *publie lundi les bonnes feuilles, sa sélection de propos au sujet de X, est bâti* [...]) ? Le fait que ce soit une locution (figée) entraîne-t-il l'emploi de l'un ou l'autre déterminant ?
- Doit-on préciser la publication de(s) **meilleures/pires** bonnes feuilles pour traiter de la qualité des extraits ou de la sélection ([...] publie ce qui constitue à mon/son avis les meilleures bonnes feuilles [...]) ?

Comment: Il me semble que « les bonnes feuilles » est l'expression figée, même si on ne cite que des extraits choisis.

Comment: @Gilles Merci ! Mais donc est-ce qu'on dirait qu'un expression figée commande le défini généralement aussi, est-ce typique ? Ou finalement c'est ma réaction à Ac.9 qui presente avec le nom au lieu d'un infinitif et devrait ajouter « publier les bonnes feuilles » et laisser entendre que c'est tout d'un bloc. Mais comme on dit, ce serait figé avec un défini pour signifier un indéfini _réel_ pourrait-on dire...

Comment: il me semble qu'il y a une connotation de "les meilleures", au sens du contexte (dans les médias ce seront souvent les plus croustillantes, les plus polémiques, les plus révélatrices au sujet de qqchose). i.e. pas des extraits choisis pour leur simple style littéraire :-)

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET Oui, justement, et donc j'ai senti une confusion, un glissement du sens _bon pour le tirage_ vers la _bonne sélection_ d'extraits; je conçois les bonnes feuilles comme un truc neutre. Ça serait seulement au contexte qu'on déterminerait si c'est neutre ou les "bonnes" parties ? Ne pas hésiter à élaborer en réponse, il n'est jamais requis de s'étendre longuement sur un sujet (comme je fais souvent) pour répondre de manière utile, qui est au final le critère sur lequel les réponses sont jugées. Merci !

Comment: L'usage actuel de "bonnes feuilles" ou de "meilleures feuilles" s'applique à un texte, rapport, document, et concerne les extraits les plus "intéressants" ou "croustillants" (au sens où chacun l'interprétera).

Answer (score 1):

J'ai regardé l'article en question : [Etats-Unis: Nixon mentait sur l'impact des bombardements au Vietnam](http://www.lexpress.fr/actualites/1/monde/etats-unis-nixon-mentait-sur-l-impact-des-bombardements-au-vietnam_1725030.html) en cherchant [sur google avec la phrase indiquée](http://bfy.tw/3S3y).

Le contexte a renforcé ma première idée, *bonne feuille* indique la rectification d'un ancien document ayant une erreur ou une information biaisée.

Dans le contexte de cette article il s'agit du *mensonge de Nixon*.